# KML should draw a red polyline or blue polyline?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

### Please tell me which one is "correct behavior as KML file format".

As you may know, the <color> tag of KML contains the color information with the order **AABBGGRR**. This is defined in the OGC KML document.

> 16.9    kml:colorType
>
> The order of expression is aabbggrr, where aa=alpha (00 to ff); bb=blue (00 to ff); gg=green (00 to ff); rr=red (00 to ff).
>   http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html

So, the `<color>7f0000ff</color>` should be red color.

---

### Example1:

With this KML file, Google Earth and Google Maps API (KmlLayer) draw a **red** polyline correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="globalStyles">
      <LineStyle id="line">
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#globalStyles</styleUrl>
      <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>-14.405821,-7.963539 -14.381448,-7.975707</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wf9a5m75/xnw0hvvf/6/
[image]

---

### Example2:

However, with this KML file, the Google Maps API draws a **blue** line, but Google Earth draws still a **red** polyline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="globalStyles">
      <LineStyle id="line">
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
      <Placemark>
        <name>runway</name>
        <styleUrl>#globalStyles</styleUrl>
        <Style>
          <LineStyle>
            <!--
            Coloring is implicitly merged from the global style, width is
            explicitly overridden.
            -->
            <width>10</width>
          </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <LineString>
          <tessellate>1</tessellate>
          <coordinates>-14.405821,-7.963539 -14.381448,-7.975707</coordinates>
        </LineString>
      </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wf9a5m75/xnw0hvvf/5/

[image]

---

### Answer from Google

I believe this is a bug of Google Maps JS API v3, and I reported this to Google.

But Google says

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> Yes. I believe Google Maps Javascript API follows the "hexadecimal" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAMKq.jpg) format for colors. What I would recommend is, if possible, to adjust your color settings to follow the hexadecimal format of Google Maps Javascript API.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71991422#comment2

Wow, does they really intend this?

---

### In real situation problem

Losing a color information means losing the meaning of the polyline/polygon.

For example, the National Oceanic and atmospheric administration (NOAA) of United states provides realtime weather hazard using KMZ file.
https://www.weather.gov/source/crh/shapefiles/

Google Earth draws polygons with correct colors (at least I think so), but the KmlLayer of Google Maps API v3 draws all blue polygons.
**Changing colors means changing meaning of the polygons.**
Don't you think this is serious problem?

[image]

---

So, in order to ask to fix the problem of Google Maps JS API v3, I need to know which one (red or blue) is correct.
Please tell me your answer with valid information.

Comment: This does appear to contravene the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer). But I suspect it's a WontFix because the colour spec predates the KML spec and it's always been that way.

Comment: Google finally accept it is a bug (reopened the case). I hope they fix this bug soon. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71991422#comment7

Answer (score 0):

For the offical interpretation of KML refer directly to the [Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) KML 2.2 standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml#downloads). Note KML 2.3 is published but not yet implemented in Google Earth or Google Maps. There has a been issue with respect to the [visibility tag](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#visibility) where Google Earth implements a behavior contrary to the KML spec but fixing would break existing code so it won't be "fixed". **In cases of contradition, the official OGC KML Standard supersedes any vendor documentation or implementation**.

KML 2.2 (Document # 07-147r2) states in section 16.8.1 the following:

> The order of expression is *aabbggrr*, where aa=alpha (00 to ff);
>   bb=blue (00 to ff); gg=green (00 to ff); rr=red (00 to ff)

It also gives an example in 16.7.1 showing that a value of *ff0000ff* is for red where the last 2-characters (ff) represent the red component.

This means that Google Earth is correctly displaying the KML rendering features using `<color>7f0000ff</color>` with a red color. Google Maps API is not rendering it correctly and is a bug.

Reference:

- KML Standard: http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml#downloads

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I already confirmed with internal person of Google Maps team, and reported as an issue. (Not fixed it though) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71991422